# Frame can't move in actionscript3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flex3, actionscript-2

Hi i have three class Mainintro.as, Gameplay.as, Lastscene.as, here i used this code to call another class.. Frame moving continuously not stoping...

```
Mainintro.as       
package 
  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;


import Globe;


public class MainIntro 
{


    public function MainIntro(Mc:MovieClip) 
    {
        Globe.self.realstage = Mc;
        Globe.self.realstage.intro_mc.stop();
        Mc.intro_mc.play_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GameStart);
        Mc.intro_mc.play_mc.buttonMode = true;
        Mc.intro_mc.ins_btn.buttonMode = true;
        var gameply:GamePlay = new GamePlay();



    }

    public function GameStart(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        {
            Globe.self.realstage.gotoAndPlay("game");


        }
    }

   }        

    }
```

Here in this class file (*Gameplay.as*) the code occurs in the `public function onClick` caused by :

```
 Globe.self.realstage.click_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);
```

Which gives a `null object reference` error but I've given the correct name for 
instance and then I tried to run ignore the errors then the frame moving not 
stopping...

```
Gameplay.as

  package 
 {
   import com.greensock.*;
   import com.greensock.easing.*;


   import flash.events.MouseEvent;
   import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import Globe;


   public class GamePlay 
    {
        var currentEntry:int = -1;

        var aList:Array =
            [
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.joker_mc, x:605.55, y:195.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.king_mc,  x:323.80, y:298.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.queen_mc, x:45.85, y:213.95},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.a_mc,     x:605.55, y:195.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.ten_mc,   x:323.80, y:298.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.five_mc,  x:45.85, y:213.95},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.two_mc,   x:605.55, y:195.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.nine_mc,  x:323.80, y:298.45},
                {card:Globe.self.realstage.four_mc,  x:45.85, y:213.95},


            ];



    public function GamePlay() 
    {
         Globe.self.realstage.stop();
         var gameply:LastScene = new LastScene();

        Globe.self.realstage.click_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
    onClick);
        Globe.self.realstage.exit_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
  lastScene);

    }
        public function lastScene(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                Globe.self.realstage.gotoAndPlay("Scene");

            }


    public  function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Unsubscribe to avoid the mess with second click.

  Globe.self.realstage.click_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
  onClick);

            // Start process.
            moveNext();
        }

    public  function moveNext():void
    {
            Globe.self.realstage.currentEntry++;

            // Stop the process if all the cards have been moved.
            if (Globe.self.realstage.currentEntry >= 
  Globe.self.realstage.aList.length) return;


            // Get the entry.
            var anEntry:Object = 
 Globe.self.realstage.aList[Globe.self.realstage.currentEntry];

            // Move the card.

    Globe.self.realstage.TweenLite.to(Globe.self.realstage.anEntry['card'], 
  .4,
  {x:Globe.self.realstage.anEntry['x'],y:Globe.self.realstage.anEntry['y'], 
  onComplete:moveNext});
    }

   }


    }
```

Comment: Errors on any timeline, cause all the scripts inside to be ignored; consequently, the timeline falls back to the default behavior of being `play`ed! Therefore, _you_ should **not** ignore the errors; but rather, if you need further help, you should edit your question, most probably add the error message and do more clarifications, specially on the `Globe` :)

Comment: What happens if you replace `Globe.self.realstage.click_mc...etc...etc` with : `e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
  onClick);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used  stop in the frame it is stopped now it's working good.